# Update a slice of tensor in torch

Tags: lua, torch

How to slice tensor's rows in `Torch` like we do in `Numpy` with `m[begin:end, :]` ?

Example of code that I want to run:

```
require 'torch'
m = torch.Tensor(10, 2):zero()
a = torch.Tensor(5, 2):fill(1)
m({{1,5}, {}}) = a -- Error at this line
```

Expected value for `m`

```
1  1
1  1
1  1
1  1
1  1
0  0
0  0
0  0
0  0
0  0
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 10x2]
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to use brackets `m[]` instead of parenthesis

Rest of the code is fine.

Comment: FYI: you might find this [Torch for NumPy users cheatseet](https://github.com/torch/torch7/wiki/Torch-for-Numpy-users) useful.